# How create a column with list of jsons if duplicated rows on other column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
buyer_id    car      color   year
john        ferrari  yellow  2022
eric        ferrari  red     2022
john        mercedes black   1990
victoria    audi     yellow  2017
```

I would like to create a new column (list of jsons in each row.

Create a column 'identical' with a list in each row:

- One element in the list if only one buyer is found in 'buyer_id':

  [{'car':..., 'color':..., 'year': ...}]
- If same buyer on several rows in 'buyer_id'

  [
  {'car':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow ', 'year': 2022},
  {'car':'mercedes', 'color': 'black', 'year': 1990}
  ]

Expected output:

```
    buyer_id   car      color   year  identical
    john       ferrari  yellow  2022  [{'car':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow ', 'year': 2022},{'car':'mercedes', 'color': 'black', 'year': 1990}]
    eric       ferrari  red     2022  [{'car':'ferrari', 'color': 'red', 'year': 2022}]
    john       mercedes black   1990  [[{'car':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow ', 'year': 2022},{'car':'mercedes', 'color': 'black', 'year': 1990}]
    victoria   audi     yellow  2017  [{'car':'audi', 'color': 'yellow', 'year': 2017}]
```

I don't know how to do this with Pandas and if it is possible.

Comment: Do you want a dictionary or a json string as output?

Comment: A dictionnary, list of jsons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) with the `orient="records"` parameter:

```
s = (df.groupby('buyer_id')
       .apply(lambda g: g.drop('buyer_id', axis=1)
                         .to_json(orient='records'))
    )
df2 = df.merge(s.rename('identical'), left_on='buyer_id', right_index=True)
```

or in place:

```
s = (df.set_index('buyer_id')
       .groupby(level='buyer_id')
       .apply(lambda g: g.to_json(orient='records'))
    )
df['identical'] = df['buyer_id'].map(s)
```

output:

```
   buyer_id       car   color  year                                                                                        identical
0      john   ferrari  yellow  2022  [{"car":"ferrari","color":"yellow","year":2022},{"car":"mercedes","color":"black","year":1990}]
1      eric   ferrari     red  2022                                                    [{"car":"ferrari","color":"red","year":2022}]
2      john  mercedes   black  1990  [{"car":"ferrari","color":"yellow","year":2022},{"car":"mercedes","color":"black","year":1990}]
3  victoria      audi  yellow  2017                                                    [{"car":"audi","color":"yellow","year":2017}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
to_dict = lambda x: x.to_dict('records')
df['identical'] = df['buyer_id'].map(df.set_index('buyer_id') \
                                       .groupby('buyer_id').apply(to_dict))
print(df)

# Output
   buyer_id       car   color  year                                                                                                   identical
0      john   ferrari  yellow  2022  [{'car': 'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'year': 2022}, {'car': 'mercedes', 'color': 'black', 'year': 1990}]
1      eric   ferrari     red  2022                                                          [{'car': 'ferrari', 'color': 'red', 'year': 2022}]
2      john  mercedes   black  1990  [{'car': 'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'year': 2022}, {'car': 'mercedes', 'color': 'black', 'year': 1990}]
3  victoria      audi  yellow  2017                                                          [{'car': 'audi', 'color': 'yellow', 'year': 2017}]
```

To export your column as JSON, you can use:

```
>>> df['identical'].to_json(orient='records', indent=2)
[
  [
    {
      "car":"ferrari",
      "color":"yellow",
      "year":2022
    },
    {
      "car":"mercedes",
      "color":"black",
      "year":1990
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "car":"ferrari",
      "color":"red",
      "year":2022
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "car":"ferrari",
      "color":"yellow",
      "year":2022
    },
    {
      "car":"mercedes",
      "color":"black",
      "year":1990
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "car":"audi",
      "color":"yellow",
      "year":2017
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.assign(identical=dd.iloc[:,1:].to_json(orient="records"))

df1.groupby('buyer_id').apply(function1)

 buyer_id   car      color   year  identical
    john       ferrari  yellow  2022  [{'car':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow ', 'year': 2022},{'car':'mercedes', 'color': 'black', 'year': 1990}]
    eric       ferrari  red     2022  [{'car':'ferrari', 'color': 'red', 'year': 2022}]
    john       mercedes black   1990  [[{'car':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow ', 'year': 2022},{'car':'mercedes', 'color': 'black', 'year': 1990}]
    victoria   audi     yellow  2017  [{'car':'audi', 'color': 'yellow', 'year': 2017}]
```